# How to toggle sidebar container for mac application development using Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am learning Mac application development. I am using Xcode 10.3 & Swift 5. I have used 2 vertical split view controller in my application. But I would like to add the functionality of hiding the middle container or view using the button in the header.

I have started from scratch to create a new project and I have only touched my Storyboard where I have used Vertical split view controller and added few constraints.

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

I would like to use that toggle button to collapse and expand the middle split view (highlighted in yellow).

Also, Is there any icon provided by Apple for showing toggling functionality or do I need to upload one into the application?

I would appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Make an IBOutlet connection to the `NSView` object in the middle.  And control its size.

Comment: @ElTomato Ty for response ... I created IBOutlet connection and added this line `windowResize.setFrameSize(newSize: NSSize)` to overload func viewDidLoad(). What should I add in setFrameSize? Ty for patience. I'm new to app developement  using swift & still learning.

Comment: "I created IBOutlet connection and added this line..."  I don't see it.  I don't even know under what class you are writing whatever it is.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Apple provide [`NSToolbarToggleSidebarItemIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbartogglesidebaritemidentifier) which sends `toggleSidebar:` to the first responder (but target can be changed if necessary during `toolbarWillAddItem:`) and it looks like this:

[image]